# Recursion java modified Fibonacci

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

```
public class ModFib
{
    public static int modFibonacci(int term)
    {
        if(term == 1)
        {
            return 3;
        }
        else if(term == 2)
        {
            return 5;
        }
        else
        {
            return modFibonacci(term - 1) + modFibonacci(term - 2) + modFibonacci(term - 3);
        }
    }
}
```

it works fine at only term - 3 but this gives a stack overflow error.

Comment: "it works fine at only term - 3 but this gives a stack overflow error." can you rephrase that a bit clearer please

Comment: once you hit `term = 3`, you recursivly end up with `modFibonacci(3-3)`, which will end in an endless recursion, as your break condition wont ever be met again, as term wont ever get to be `1` or `2` again and you´ll endlessly end up the in the `else` part recursivly calling your method.

Comment: @Bango Sorry for lack of clarity. return modFibonacci(term - 1) + modFibonacci(term - 2) works fine but when i add the third term it stops working.

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

need to add condition like

```
if(term == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```